# Too much data given by "InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity" - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I want to have few outputs from one cell. For this I use:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Code is doing well, but it's giving me some unwanted data.

```
Out[1]: <Figure size 2500x800 with 0 Axes>
Out[1]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1a22e8ca50>
Out[1]: Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Przetrwanie, (0 = Zmarli / 1 = Ocaleni)')
Out[1]: [Text(0, 0.5, 'Liczba')]
```

I can use some flag options like: 'all', 
'last', 
'last_expr', 
'none', 
'last_expr_or_assign'

but none of the options solves the problem :/

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html?highlight=InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity), "last_expr"` means outputting only the last expression. You can also refer to a nice [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-effortlessly-optimize-jupyter-notebooks-e864162a06ee) from https://towardsdatascience.com for more details.

If option `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "last_expr"` didn't work in your case, please provide more details.

Comment: This should be a comment instead.

Comment: @DavidLee Does it look like an answer now? If not, I'll move it to the comment area.

Comment: I think the answer wants to say that `'last_expr'` should solve the problem of  Adrian. Unfortunately the question does not explain why Adrian thinks `'last_expr'` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly I see two approaches to resolve it:

a) Use `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr'` (default) and split your cells so that they always contain the expression to display the value of as the last one. You can combine this approach with `display()` as shown below.

b) Use `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'none'` and the `display()` function to show the values you want to show:

```py
get_ipython().ast_node_interactivity = 'none'
```

```py
1 + 2
display(1 + 3)
1 + 4
display(1 + 5)
1 + 6
```

Output:

```py
4
6
```